# Is there a quick way to do a cksum on output going to stdout?

Tags: diff, ksh

I want to compare the a list of files in two directories quickly.  I can use the following

```
    $    ls /opt/myapp/ >> ~/myapplist
    $    cksum ~/myapplist
3476215496 7657 /u/compll07/ojblass/myapplist

    $    ls /opt/myapp2/ >> ~/myapp2list
    $    cksum ~/myapp2list
3476215496 7657 /u/compll07/ojblass/myapp2list
```

And compare the checksums of the output.  I would like to just do a cksum of the output of a command and I have tried

```
$    cksum `ls /opt/myapp/`
```

But that doesn't work.  Is there a slicker way to do this in one command in ksh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`% echo hello, world | cksum -`
`1398783287 13 -`

`-` tells `cksum` to use stdin as input.

`cksum` actually uses stdin by default anyway:

`% echo hello, world | cksum`
`1398783287 13`

I find the second form prettier, actually.